# Tree view Array Value Update

Tags: javascript, reactjs, angular

I have tree view Array and I need to update bookmarked key value `true`..
Now I have `id:5` using this id update bookmarked value

```
let articles = [
   {
      "id":1,
      "title":"sample-magazine",
      "children":[
         {
            "id":3,
            "title":"cat1",
            "children":[
               {
                  "id":4,
                  "title":"page1",
                  "children":[

                  ],
                  "page":{
                     "id":2,
                     "position":2,
                     "thumbnail":null,
                     "bookmarked":null
                  },
                  "thumbnail":null,
                  "isCat":false
               },
               {
                  "id":5,
                  "title":"page2",
                  "children":[

                  ],
                  "page":{
                     "id":3,
                     "position":3,
                     "thumbnail":null,
                     "bookmarked":null
                  },
                  "thumbnail":null,
                  "isCat":false
               }
            ],
            "page":{
               "id":1,
               "position":1,
               "thumbnail":null,
               "bookmarked":null
            },
            "thumbnail":null,
            "isCat":true
         }
      ],
      "page":null,
      "thumbnail":null,
      "isCat":null
   }
]
```

Thanks In advance

Comment: You might want to re-format your array. It's not showing up well in your post. Also, do you have some array looping code you can post? Or you're starting from scratch?

Answer (score 0):

What you can Do is a recursive search and when you find the value you can set it there.

```
const search = (tree, target) => {
      if (tree.id === target) {
        tree.page.bookmarked = true;
      }
      for (const child of tree.children) {
        const res = search(child, target);    
        if (res) {
          return res;
        }
      }
    };
    
    search(articles[0], 5);
    
    console.log(articles)
```